# Why will tone.js play a note in desktor browser, but not on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

I'm trying to play a note using tone.js.

In my browser (on both Safari and Firefox) the note will play, but on IOS (Tested on both Chrome and Safari) it doesn't.

I'm using Tone.start() and only play audio in the `then` callback as the docs state that you should.

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    box.style.display = 'none';
    stopButton.style.display = 'block';
    Tone.start().then(() => {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            const note = getRandomNote();
            synth.triggerAttackRelease(note + "4", "4n");
        }, 2000)
      
    })

})
```

Why might this happen?

Answer (score 3):

So I had my phone on silent.... that was the issue.

Comment: i had the same 'problem' :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, Tone.js doesn't play any sound on the newer iPhones and iPads when the device is muted. My solution was to play a silent mp3 on user interaction, using a native HTML audio element to activate the sound. I do this before playing the sound that I actually want to hear.

```
<audio>
    <source src="/silent.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

You can use Javascript to get the audio element to start playing on user interaction. So select the audio element, and call it's play() method right before starting the audio you actually want to hear.

```
audioElement.play();
```

I tested on the following devices on LambdaTest (highly recommended if you don't own an iOS device):

- iPhone 8 13.4
- iPhone 12 17.2
- iPhone 13 Mini 17.2
- iPhone 14 17.2
- iPhone 15 17.2